# Can a Maven scala project be run in databricks?

Tags: maven, databricks

We can run our Maven scala project via devops pipeline.

Is it possible to run the project on a databricks cluster? Ideally invoked from a databricks job?

There doesn't seem to be any info on this subject, so I assume it's not possible or is unpopular.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you're using Databricks to execute jar file that is built by your build/release pipeline. There is always a separation between build (DevOps pipeline) and execution (Databricks) environments.

Technically it's possible to clone code to Databricks cluster & build it there (via init scripts), but it really not makes sense imho...

Comment: thanks for your reply. We have a test framework that runs our product, and the performance is best if run on a decent spec cluster. The test framework can be run using maven test locally or on build agent, but for performance we wish to run it on the cluster.  Will look into init scripts possibility. Thanks